# Vue: How to update elements that use data when data is changed?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have this simple script which when you press a button, it inserts some HTML, a FontAwesome icon. Each button is rendered by a 'v-for' loop and the text comes from the 'data' object.

I also have another button `change data` that overwrites that data object. When you press it, all three buttons change text as you would expect. However, if you click any of the first three buttons to add icons into them, then change the data, only the buttons without the icons update.

How can I force them all to update regardless of whether the HTML has been changed? If all three buttons have an icon in them, then I press the change data button, I expect all buttons to only then contain the text of the updated data object - no icons.

I suspect it's because I'm overrwriting `{{word}}` with `${icon} ${e.target.textContent}` in a sense?

```js
const V = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    words: ["One", "Two", "Three"]
  },
  methods: {
    addFa: function(e) {
      const icon = `<i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>`;
      e.target.innerHTML = `${icon} ${e.target.textContent}`;
    },
    changeData: function() {
      this.words = ["Four", "Five", "Six"];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="addFa($event)" v-for="word in words">{{word}}</button>
  <button @click="changeData()">Change data</button>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you show/hide the <i> element instead of adding it on click?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate

Comment: adds `:key="word"` to force-remount, then should meet your requirements (like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6tk3r0d/)). The reason of `Dom can't be updated when change data' is caused by you inserted Dom nodes which causes vnode mismatch with the actual dom,

Comment: @SujilMaharjan Because I don't want to do that - note that this is only pseudo code.

Comment: @Sphinx Your method works, please formulate your comment into an answer so I may accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue failed to update the Dom because you manually insert some Dom nodes which causes mismatch with Vnodes'.

But you can use `:key="word"` or **other unique values** to force-remount (check [Vue Guide: key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key)). It will re-generate the Dom node based on current state (fa-icons will be removed because it is not a part of the template, fortunately it meet your requirements which doesn't need to display icons after data change).

Below is one demo:

```js
const V = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    words: ["One", "Two", "Three"]
  },
  methods: {
    addFa: function(e) {
      const icon = `<i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>`;
      e.target.innerHTML = `${icon} ${e.target.textContent}`;
    },
    changeData: function() {
      this.words = ["Four", "Five", "Six"];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="addFa($event)" v-for="word in words" :key="word">{{word}}</button>
  <button @click="changeData()">Change data</button>
</div>
```